# Create html like table in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How to create html like table in Oracle ADF? The following

```
<af:table>
```

adds also headers, which is not desired in my case. I need just a simple table like layout, with no margins between rows and cells. Something like this (note: instead of text may be anything, layouts, imags, etc.):

[image]

I can create something similar with **panelGridLayout**, but when adding borders, the margins between rows still remain.

```
<af:panelGridLayout id="pgl3">
        <af:gridRow height="auto" id="gr4">
          <af:gridCell id="gc9"
                       inlineStyle="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; border-right:solid thin; border-left:solid thin; border-top:solid thin; border-bottom:solid thin; border-color:Silver;">
            <af:outputText value="Text1"/>
          </af:gridCell>
          <af:gridCell id="gc8"
                       inlineStyle="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; border-right:solid thin; border-top:solid thin; border-bottom:solid thin; border-color:Silver;">
            <af:outputText value="Text2"/>
          </af:gridCell>
        </af:gridRow>
        <af:gridRow height="auto" id="gr6">
          <af:gridCell id="gc10"
                       inlineStyle="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; border-right:solid thin; border-left:solid thin; border-top:solid thin; border-bottom:solid thin; border-color:Silver;">
            <af:outputText value="Text3"/>
          </af:gridCell>
          <af:gridCell inlineStyle="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; border-right:solid thin; border-top:solid thin; border-bottom:solid thin; border-color:Silver;"
                       id="gc6">
            <af:outputText value="Text4"/>
          </af:gridCell>
        </af:gridRow>
      </af:panelGridLayout>
```

Which will look like:

[image]

Also,I noticed this solution ( https://community.oracle.com/thread/1104448), but I would prefer to avoid ADF table, since I only need layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use JSF `<h:panelGrid>`, It will give the look and feel of an html table:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="pg1" width="100%" frame="box" rules="all">
    <af:outputText value="Text1" id="ot1"/>
    <af:outputText value="Text2" id="ot2"/>
    <af:outputText value="Text3" id="ot3"/>
    <af:outputText value="Text4" id="ot4"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work or not, but trying it does not hurt,
put your **html tags** inside the **`value`** attribute of **`<af:outputFormatted>`** **for example:**

```
<af:outputFormatted styleUsage="yourStyle"
                value="<b>any output</b>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*[Trinidad table](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/trh_tableLayout.html)* will give you exact html-table layout.

However you should avoid using html things in your adf application if possible.
 If your requirements is only to have table without header, you can style
 *af:table* and turn off headers layer in your skin like this:

```
.noHeader af|column::column-header-cell{
   display: none;
}
```

*af:panelGroupLayout* in **layout=horizontal** mode will render html table around its content too, however you will have only one row and almost no control of it behavior.

*af:panelGridLayout* will render grid that may be used as table layout too.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the listView component - http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/listView/listViewTabular.jspx